# Serving single html page with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a simple Spring Boot app that uses Spring Boot Web. I placed my index.html into the templates subdirectory of the resources directory as per the Spring Boot docs. I've defined inside the application.properties file:

spring.mvc.view.prefix=classpath:/templates/

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html

My WebMvcConfigurerAdapter looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    super.addViewControllers(registry);
}   
}
```

My problem is I cant seem to serve index.html at http://localhost:8080.
I get the following error: 
"javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'".

How can I fix this without the use of a controller?

Kind regards,
Dave

Comment: Annotate the class with @Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to serve static content from Spring Boot application you just need to place them in `src/main/resources/static` - no other configuration needed.

- put `index.html` to `src/main/resources/static/index.html`
- delete properties from `application.properties`
- delete `addViewControllers` method and `@EnableWebMvc` annotation - you can actually delete whole class
- access index by going to `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: Cheers Maciej but I've tried the above suggestions and now the error produced is: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Comment: Did you remove also `@EnableWebMvc` annotation from your config? I updated the answer.